# C# MDI form container wrap child form

Tags: c#

I have a container MDI Form in C# with a 2 children in different sizes.

Is there a way when i initialize the new child to the container - i will progmatically set the size of the container to wrap the child form ?

Answer (score 0):

when you opening new form from Mdi parent set its property `size`:

```
Form childForm = new Form();
childForm.MdiParent = this;
childForm.Size = new Size(100, 100);//edit size
childForm.Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i found my answer thanks to IRSOG deleted answer:

```
    Form form= new Form();
    form.MdiParent = this;
    this.Size = new Size(form.Width, form.Height);
    form.Show();
```

hope it will help someone